# Разница между push_back и emplace_back

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Подскажите, в чем разница между старым добрым `vector::push_back()` и пришедшим в новом стандарте `vector::emplace_back()`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`push_back` добавляет копию объекта (или обеспечивает перемещение, если возможно), а `emplace_back` создает объект непосредственно в конце вектора, т.е. без лишнего копирования (или перемещения).

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что для корректной работы emplace_back у типа, хранящегося в векторе, должен быть реализован конструктор с семантикой перемещения, иначе emplace_back вырождается в push_back?

Comment: `push_back` есть для rvalue(xvalue) поэтому копирование вовсе необязатаельно

Comment: @vldmalov, одно с другим не связано. `emplace_back` стал возможен благодаря появлению variadic templates и forwarding(rvalue-ссылки): это просто отложенный вызов конструктора, который произойдёт в кишках вектора, а не вне его, как это происходит с `push_back`. В `push_back` передаётся объект типа `T`(при условии `std::vector<T>`), а в `emplace_back` передаются аргументы из которых `T` может быть сконструирован.

Comment: @ixSci будет перемещение, но это всё равно не *создание по месту*. За замечание спасибо, обновил ответ.

Comment: @alexolut: `emplace_back()` позволяет избежать как лишнего копирования так и перемещения: только аргументы передаются. Например, [фраза *"I am being moved."* не печатается в случае `emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)

Comment: @jfs разве это не указано у меня в ответе?

Comment: @alexolut: ваши слова: *"@ixSci будет перемещение"*

Comment: @jfs это про `push_back` речь шла (жалко, что в комментариях не видно на какую строку ответ публикуется, как в чате).

Answer (score 32):

Проще на примере...

```
struct Item
{
    int a, b, c;
    Item(int a,int b,int c):a(a),b(b),c(c){}
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<Item> x;
    // x.push_back(1,2,3);    <- не скомпилируется!
    x.emplace_back(1,2,3);
}
```

Как видите, `push_back`'у нужен объект типа элемента (или приводимый). А вот `emplace`'у просто передаются аргументы, *как конструктору*.

P.S. Понятно, что этим конструктором может быть и копирующий конструктор :) Так что

```
x.emplace_back(Item(0,1,2));
```

тоже работает.

Answer (score 1):

`x.push_back({ 1,2,3 }); // Работает`

Я бы сказал, что push_back более универсален. С emplace_back есть нюансы в более сложных алгоритмах. Например при копировании элементов многомерного вектора в одномерный. С виду работает, а компилируешь, ругается. Я бы сказал они один другой дополняют. Если emplace_back работает оставляем его, а если дивные ошибки лезут, то ставим push_back и добавляем {} как я выше показал.