# вызов "лишних" конструкторов emplace_back & push_back для std::vector есть ли выгода?

Tags: c++, c++11

Не понимаю в чем разница между двумя методами. В описании говориться, что emplace_back вызывает лишь один конструктор, когда как push_back дополнительно вызывает и конструктор перемещения:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Здесь встречал подобный вопрос, где так же говориться, что emplace_back не вызывает лишних конструкторов, но у меня в примере вызывает еще как.
Примерчик работает когда вставляются по одному элементу, а если вставлять несколько, к примеру:

```
std::vector<President> elections;
std::cout << "emplace_back:\n";
elections.emplace_back("Nelson", "South Africa", 1994);
std::cout <<" ____________\n";    
elections.emplace_back("Gosha", "South Africa", 1994);
std::cout <<" ____________\n";
elections.emplace_back("Kostya", "South Africa", 1994);
std::cout <<" ____________\n";
elections.emplace_back("Vanya", "South Africa", 1994);
std::cout <<" ____________\n";
elections.emplace_back("Kseniya", "South Africa", 1994);
std::cout <<" ____________\n";
```

То неясным образом и хаотично вызывает конструктор перемещения несколько раз:

> ```
> emplace_back:
> I am being constructed.   Nelson
>  ____________
> I am being constructed.   Gosha
> I am being moved. Nelson
>  ____________
> I am being constructed.   Kostya
> I am being moved. Nelson
> I am being moved. Gosha
>  ____________
> I am being constructed.   Vanya
>  ____________
> I am being constructed.   Kseniya
> I am being moved. Nelson
> I am being moved. Gosha
> I am being moved. Kostya
> I am being moved. Vanya
>  ____________
>
> push_back:
> I am being constructed.   Franklin 
> I am being moved. Franklin
> ```

Если использовать push_back списком инициализации, то emplace_back не нужен?!

```
elections.push_back({"Vanya", "South Africa", 1994});
```

В чем может быть дело и все ли верно и как быть с этой функцией.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разница между push\_back и emplace\_back](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570042/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-push-back-%d0%b8-emplace-back)

Comment: уточнил заголовок, суть вопроса не дублирует указанную выше тему

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так вектор растет, вот и перемещения.
При росте вектора он выделяет новый (больший) кусок памяти, и перемещает значения туда.

Вызывайте `reserve()`.

Comment: Точно, это решило проблему. Возник второй вопрос: почему вектор растет используя предыдущие введенные значения и использует конструктор перемещения?

Comment: Вектор определён как хранилище в одном непрерывном блоке памяти. Поэтому он при выделении нового блока должен перемещать уже существующие элементы. Если это не устраивает, то надо использовать другие контейнеры (например, list).

Comment: @Abyx у меня паршивенько с гроканием стандарта C++ - разве deque запрещено перемещать элементы для оптимизации хранения?

Comment: Ага, тогда тоже годится.

Comment: Можете использовать односвязный (std::forward_list)/двухсвязный списки (std::list). Каждый узел списка храниться в отдельной области памяти и связывается с соседями указателями, поэтому никакой реалокации не будет. Но тут важно, как будете с данными работать, понадобиться ли произвольный доступ к элементам списка.